# Quando Brake Pads - Anyone know where I can get a pair

Tags: disc-brake, brake-pads

I have just bought a second hand Diamond Back Sorrento mountain bike, the bike is about 5 - 6yrs old apparently and needs some minor maintenance.

The brakes are absolutely shot and I need to replace the brake pads front and back but I can't find the correct pads, they are **Quando** mechanical cable disc brakes. They seem pretty budget and I have never heard of the brand of brakes before and can't find any information online about them.

See images below, they are **23mm diameter** and fit flush into the caliper which is also **23mm diameter**. They are held in place magnectically... Anyone got any idea where I could get similar pads that are the correct size. I really don't want to have to buy new calipers just because I can't find the correct size pads... HELP!

You can see images here - http://www.dropbox.com/gallery/2198561/1/brake-pads?h=f86002

Answer (score 1):

They appear very similar to Avid BB5 pads.I would take your pads to your local shop and see if they match.The tab on the Avid pad looks to be a little longer but might fit.Tektro also has two numbers that look similar IOX.11 and L10.11

Comment: Great thanks I am still trying to hunt down a pair of compatible pads, I'm slowly getting somewhere now, I will post back when I have found the correct pads and have them installed

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to confirm that I have now found compatible brake pads for the Quando mechanical cable disc brakes. Some very helpful person at Evans Cycles recommended these pads that fit perfectly

Magura Louise Clara 2000, Louise 1999-2001

http://www.clarkscycles.com/index.php/html/product/pagetype/aftermarket/id/vrx800c-disc-pad-sintered

I now have brakes that work perfectly.. hope this is useful for anyone looking for brake pads for these brakes.

Comment: Many thanks for posting this Andy, I have spent hours trying to answer the same question. Much appreciated.