# Mechanical disc brake caliper round pads 23 mm diameter

Tags: disc-brake, mechanical, brake-pads

I’m trying to find round brake pads of ca. 23mm diameter.  They are for a Valk bike brand sold online in Australia. There is no brand or model evident on the brake caliper or levers. Almost certainly a generic Chinese or Taiwanese product.

The supplier/importer has no stock until the end of December! The pads visually resemble the Alhonga Zoom /SNG pad, except they are 23mm diameter rather than 18.5mm.
See https://www.bicyclepartswarehouse.com.au/product/brake-disc-pads-alhonga-mechanical-zoom-18-5mm-backing-plate/
They are completely round except for a short stumpy leg of about 5x6 mm, just like the Alhonga Zoom pictured.

Has anyone spotted this pad for sale anywhere, and/or some maker’s brand name and model which might help me source a supply? Believe me I’ve done a lot of online searching before asking here.

Comment: That diameter sounds close for [BB5](https://www.chainreactioncycles.com/nukeproof-avid-bb5-mtb-disc-brake-pads/rp-prod129753), but the handle on a BB5 pad is longer (and the actual pad doesn't cover the whole round backing).  BB5-style pads are common on generic brakes

Comment: I can't find a figure for the BB5 pads diameter.  Annoyingly [I measured some once](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/62962/total-brake-failure-trying-to-understand-what-happened) but only noted the difference between 2 types, not the absolute value, and my commuting toolkit doesn't have any in

Comment: Sounds very similar to tektro novella/iox

Comment: @NathanKnutson Tektro are really confusing - ancient novela seemed to use different pads to IOX, while novela from about the last 10 years uses the same

Comment: You may find it easier to replace the caliper. Its entirely possible it will also be cheaper.

Answer (score 3):

I can't post images with a comment so this is barely an answer but it may be of assistance. There are a few pads that are circular and 23mm in diameter, hopefully this will help narrow your search.

There are also others that these pads fit I'm sure. The list beneath each is definitely not exhaustive.

[image]
[image]
[image]

These come from US Distributor JBI's website:
[JBI Disc Pads](https://www.jbi.bike/site/disc_pads.php)

Answer (score 1):

After re-reading I think you're looking to get these sooner rather than later, so I thought about not posting at all, but then reconsidered in the event it might help. If you don't mind the (potentially) lengthy shipping time, and don't mind getting them from Aliexpress, you can find those there.

I saw some listings which show 'frying pan' style brake pads with 22.8 mm diameter but even for this diameter there are a few sizes that depict different overall length (because of the different length of the 'handle').

I don't want to list a specific seller here as the link will eventually expire but just search under 'bicycle disc brake pad' and many listings will come up.

Edit: per Chris H's recommendation, here's a link to a listing that shows several pad styles with dimensions.
[link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000968187037.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000014.5.c17f1f734Q2s9F&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreOtherSeller&scm=1007.33416.213724.0&scm_id=1007.33416.213724.0&scm-url=1007.33416.213724.0&pvid=e36e5be7-0f4d-417c-adf3-b917ceb3860d&_t=gps-id:pcDetailBottomMoreOtherSeller,scm-url:1007.33416.213724.0,pvid:e36e5be7-0f4d-417c-adf3-b917ceb3860d,tpp_buckets:668%232846%238115%232000&&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22:%2210000012952061793%22,%22sceneId%22:%2223416%22%7D)

Also if you scroll down you'll see 'More to love' which will be listings from other sellers that have similar items. Usually when browsing Aliexpress listings, my initial search from the home page finds something, but not exactly what I'm looking for or the price might not be right etc but browsing the 'More to Love' will usually home in on what I'm looking for.

Comment: A link would be helpful to the OP even if it might rot.  Here's a [selection of pads](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002020396262.html?spm=a2g0o.search0304.0.0.48a97c40q5cAae&ad_pvid=2021111908510910722127268713640020817796_1&s=p), with (unusually for AliExpress) useful information: dimensions that matter, and what they fit, to help the OP track some down locally

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the ideas. Very helpful. The “panhandle” is too wide on the Tektros, and too long on the BB5.

The answer came from another question on here, [Quando Brake Pads - Anyone know where I can get a pair](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8410/quando-brake-pads-anyone-know-where-i-can-get-a-pair/8588#8588). Which I found subsequent to asking this. For a Magura model!

What a wonderful expert group this is!